# Unable to create schema with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: schema, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to get started with Castle ActiveRecord (following the ["Getting started with ActiveRecord"](http://castlecasts.com/Episodes/5/Show/getting-started-with-activerecord) screencast).

I created two ActiveRecord classes, one of them named `User`. I added the relevant strings to the `app.config` file, and I initialize using:

```
var config = ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance;
ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof(User).Assembly, config);

ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException:
>   Could not create the schema --->
>   NHibernate.HibernateException:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'User'. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'User'

I uploaded a small reproduction to http://bitbucket.org/hmemcpy/general, could someone please tell me what have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'*User*' is a reserved word in SQL server, the SQL command being executed is:

```
create table User (Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
                   UserName NVARCHAR(255) null unique,
                   primary key (Id))
```

It's illegal to name a table User in SQL server, but it is legal to name it *[User]*.

```
create table [User] (Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
                   UserName NVARCHAR(255) null unique,
                   primary key (Id))
```

As a solution you can define different names for tables and columns named by reserved words:

```
[ActiveRecord("[User]")]
public class User : ActiveRecordLinqBase<User>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Property(Unique = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [HasMany]
    public IList<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

When using a *[*  *]* around the table name, reserved names are allowed. The same is relevant for relation columns:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Activity : ActiveRecordLinqBase<Activity>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("[User]")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, any other name like `[ActiveRecord("SomeUser")]` will work.

Comment: Thanks Elish :) I figured as much, I renamed the `User` class to `XUser` and it worked :)